# Angularfire bindTo for subobjects

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I have a structure for userdatas under `$rootScope.myUserData`, like: `$rootScope.myUserData.basicData`, `$rootScope.myUserData.AC`, for trying to optimize the queries through Firebase.

The problem is that if I want to bind them nicely under `$rootScope.myUserData` - subObjects, I cant do this:

```
$rootScope.myUserData.basicData = $firebase( new Firebase(resourceURL) ).$asObject();
$rootScope.myUserData.basicData.$bindTo($rootScope.myUserData, "basicData");
```

For example this should work fine:

```
$rootScope.basicData = $firebase( new Firebase( resourceURL ) 
$rootScope.basicData.$bindTo($rootScope, "basicData");
```

If I understand correctly, you have to bind it straight to rootScope and can't bind it to e.g. `$rootScope.myUserData.basicData`.

Is there any way around this problem, with using the structure I have now with `$rootScope.myUserData` subobjects or is the only solution to change the structure i.e. `$rootScope.myUserData_basicData`?

Comment: Sorry, but it's no clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Can you edit your question to include a minimal, but complete, example of what you've done and what doesn't work about it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry for the bad example. I try to be clear, but usually end up not doing so. Please tell me if the current example is not clear enough. 

Basically I just want to bind a scope.object.subobject to itself. I do not know specifics how the angularfire works on the binding, but this seems to be the only way to bind existing scope object to work with 3-way data binding.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I bind my synchronized objects (including their subobjects) and arrays to the `$scope` and they work without problems. Aren't you causing your own problems by binding to the `$rootScope`  and trying to optimize something that doesn't need optimizing?

Comment: I just simply don't want to use an object-structure like: $scope.user_basicData = firebaseReference, $scope.user_AC = anotherFirebaseReference, $scope.user_views = yetAnotherReference (since the userdata is not located in one reference-tree, but rather on several). It's more of a object-logical / structure issue I'm facing. I might be thinking it the wrong way, please give your thoughts on that, but to me that seems to be the most clear structure.